# make exiftool error if input file is not an image

Tags: exiftool

I just tried to get the embedded color profile of a csv file, which returns no input

```sh
$ exiftool -a -S -G0 -ColorSpace -InteropIndex -WhitePoint -PrimaryChromaticities -Gamma -ICC_Profile:all my_data.csv
$
```

and just running `exiftool my_data.csv` prints stuff and doesn't set an error status code

```
$ exiftool my_data.csv 
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.05
File Name                       : my_data.csv
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 84 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:03:22 19:06:19-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:03:22 19:06:23-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:03:22 19:06:19-04:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : CSV
File Type Extension             : csv
MIME Type                       : text/csv
MIME Encoding                   : us-ascii
Newlines                        : Unix LF
Delimiter                       : Comma
Quoting                         : Double quotes
Column Count                    : 11
Row Count                       : 241
$ echo $?
0
$
```

Can I tell exiftool to error out if the input isn't an image somehow? Do I have to check the `File Type` and handle it myself or let the error happen later in my code? I don't know what all valid image file types are.

Answer (score 0):

Not without editing the source code.

You could exclude file types with the [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension), using two dashes instead of just one.  For example, you could add
`--ext txt --ext csv`
and exiftool will not process files with a CSV or TXT extension.

You could also use the [`-if` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#if-NUM-EXPR) to check if the `MIMEType` is an image
`exiftool -if "$MIMEType=~/^image/" …`

If this command is run under Unix/Mac, change the double quotes to single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.